# query regarding Visits in Omniture

Tags: google-analytics, adobe-analytics

Suppose i have 3 e-commerce pages like in amazon etc. where page one has details of a product, page 2 has payment detail and page 3 is a thank you page.

Can the following scenario feasible -

Page 1 has 10 visits, Page 2 has 12 Visits, Page 3 has again 10 visits.

Comment: What happens if someone sits on page on page 2, let's the session expire and then comes back to complete the purchase?

Comment: yes it is possible, but to understand how, first you need to understand all of the ways visitors can access those pages on your site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, page 2 could certainly have 12 visits. If two users went from page 1 to page 2, left the tab open for more than 30 minutes, refreshed the page, then want to page 3, you would end up with the exact scenario specified.